# What is wrong on my javascript object-literal instance?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I'm trying to instance a object-literal on my javascript code, but is not working.

```
    var user = {
        name = "User Name",
        email = "user@teste.com",
        birthdate = new Date(1980,1,30)
    };

    console.log(user);
```

Comment: The `=` signs inside the object initializer should be `:`

Comment: [Introducing JavaScript objects - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're assigning values within the object, use `:` You can assign values outside of the object with `user.name = "User Name"`

```js
    var user = {
        name : "User Name",
        email : "user@teste.com",
        birthdate : new Date(1980,1,30)
    };

    console.log(user);
```

Comment: Wow, I really made a beginner error, but thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I brain locked on an easy one and got a quick answer here yesterday. We feel silly but save a bunch of time.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to initialize the object is

```
let obj = {
   key1: value1
   key2: value2
   ...
}
```

`=` is assignment operator you need to use `:`

Comment: Ohh, my mistake, tks